# How to Read text file each line after space in python

Tags: python, list

Now I got the text file like

```
Mary Apple
Tom Pear
Harry Banana 
..
```

What I expect:

```
x = [ry, m, rry, ...] 
c = [Apple, Pear, Banana, ...]
```

How do I put the fruit into the list c and put the name(only from the thrid letter) into the list x?

Here is my code but it does't work

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    for i in data:
        x = (i.split()[0])
    for i in data:
        c = (i.split()[1])
```

Comment: You say you want ```[ry, om, rry, ...]```, but what's the logic behind that?

Comment: Sorry, Mistyped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get both `ry` and `om` and `rry`. Like you could get `ry` with `m` by using the slice `[2:]`. Your current input and output logic doesn't make sense. However, here's something you can try:

```
x = []
c = []
with open("file.txt") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    for i in data:
        x.append(i.split()[0][2:]) #ry, m, rry
        c.append(i.split()[1])
print(x,c)
```

You could also use list comprehension but that would just cause you to return two loops. I recommend using a dictionary for this like:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    values = {i.split()[0]:i.split()[1]  for i in data}
print(values)
# Output: {'Mary': 'Apple', 'Tom': 'Pear', 'Harry': 'Banana'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do like this:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    data = f.readlines()

    x = []
    c = []
    for i in data:
        line = i.split()
        x.append(line[0][2:])
        c.append(line[1])
```

And btw its `[ry, m, rry]` not `om` from `Tom`.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines() 
    x = []
    c = []
    for line in lines:
        data = line.split(" ")
        name = data[0]
        fruit = data[1]

        c.append(fruit)

        if len(name) < 4:
            x.append(name[len(name) // 2:])
        else:
            x.append(name[2:])

    print(x) # ['ry', 'om', 'rry']
    print(c) # ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Banana']
```

Comment: This would also print `\n` which is not needed.

Comment: I like that you jump through hoops to get the `om` done, OP already edited his post.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like @TheMyth almost got it, but doesn't clean the result of the trailing newline character `\n`.
EDIT: Nevermind, @TheMyth was right.

The following accomplishes this:

```py
x = []
c = []

with open("file.txt") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    for i in data:
        x.append(i.split(' ')[0][2:])
    for i in data:
        a = i.split(' ')[1]
        c.append(a.split('\n')[0])

print(x)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
['ry', 'm', 'rry']
['Apple', 'Pear', 'Banana']
```

Hope that helps!

@TheMyth
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by I'm not cleaning the trailing results for `\n`. My code doesn't even include `\n` in the first place (nor in the output).

Comment: @TheMyth, I just took another look. Apparently `c.append(i.split()[1])` within your code vs `a = i.split(' ')[1]` within my code function differently, and yours doesn't include the trailing `\n` within the .txt file. I have edited my answer. Do you mind explaining why this is the case?

Comment: Both `.split(' ')` and `.split()` do the same exact function. The default argument is `' '` so you don't need to specify it.

Comment: @TheMyth, yet they don't produce the same output.
CODE: `c.append(i.split()[1])`, OUTPUT: `['ry', 'm', 'rry'] ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Banana']`
CODE: `c.append(i.split(' ')[1])`, OUTPUT: `['ry', 'm', 'rry'] ['Apple\n', 'Pear\n', 'Banana\n']`

Same file, same everything, just inserting `' '` within the `.split()` function.

Comment: I ran both the codes and they returned me the same output without the `\n` one. I don't know why you're getting something different. Try checking your input again.

Comment: @TheMyth see the screenshot I edited into my answer.